# Do you need to install Scala separately if you use sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

Reason I ask, is because it's possible to specify a Scala version in the `build.sbt` file (using `scalaVersion` setting), and once you do that, sbt will automatically download that Scala version to use with the project.

I also seem to remember that despite having Scala 2.11.1 on my system, sbt would compile and run with Scala 2.10 if no version was specified.

So the question is, do I need to install Scala separately if I got sbt installed?

Comment: The answer is no, sbt downloads everything. :)

Comment: @DaunnC That could have been an answer, and you could have more reputation by now...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you don't need it. `sbt` will download Scala for you.

If you install `sbt-extras` (basically just a script) you don't even need to download `sbt`: it will automatically download the sbt launcher you need. Very handy since you just need to specify `sbt.version` in your `build.properties` and you're good to go.

Edit: removed my comment about not being able to do `sbt console` in an empty directory, since both `sbt` and `sbt-extras` support it now.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about not being able to `sbt console` in an empty (non-project) directory? Just did `mkdir empty-dir`, `cd empty-dir` and then `sbt console` and it worked well. It doesn't for you?

Comment: No. It complains that this is not a SBT project and I should run `sbt init` first But, as I said, I am using sbt-extras, maybe SBT supports it.

Comment: I can confirm it that sbt itself does work in an empty directory using defaults for settings that constitute a project. That's why I'm wondering why the comment *even better `sbt-extras`* that in this case makes things worse.

Comment: Because `sbt-extras` may not be ideal to work with the console but it has nice features to work on an actual project.

Comment: Would you mind editing the answer so it holds the remark about `sbt-extras` that may break the feature of sbt considering any non-project directory a project? I wouldn't mind removing the remark altogether either.